# Object escapes the window in pygame . How to prevent it from doing so?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I am python beginner and wanted to create a space invader game. But I'm facing an issue.

The player object escapes the pygame window if I press the left arrow key or the right arrow key for a longer duration of time.

Here's my code -

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
pygame.display.set_caption('RESCUE THE SPACESHIP')

close = False

spaceship_velocity = 0
spaceship_X = 550
spaceship_Y = 670

spacehip_img = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')


while not close:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                spaceship_velocity -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                spaceship_velocity += 1

    #Doesn't seems to work
    if spaceship_X < -25:
        spaceship_X == -25
    if spaceship_X > 1125:
        spaceship_X == 1125

    spaceship_X = spaceship_X + spaceship_velocity
    print(spaceship_X)

    window.fill((255,255,255))
    window.blit(spacehip_img , (spaceship_X , spaceship_Y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Before asking this question I've tried this but it doesn't seems to restrict the spaceship within the window

```
if spaceship_X < -25:
    spaceship_X == -25
if spaceship_X > 1125:
    spaceship_X == 1125
```

Any ideas how to fix it up?

Comment: `spaceship_X == -25` -> `spaceship_X =-25` and `spaceship_X == 1125` -> `spaceship_X = 1125`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I CHANGED

```
==
```

TO

```
=
```

AND IT WORKED PERFECTLY FOR ME

BEFORE

```
if spaceship_X < -25:
    spaceship_X == -25
if spaceship_X > 1125:
    spaceship_X == 1125
```

AFTER

```
if spaceship_X < -25:
    spaceship_X = -25
if spaceship_X > 1125:
    spaceship_X = 1125
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the position check after `spaceship_X = spaceship_X + spaceship_velocity`, and perhaps change it to:

```py
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
if spaceship_X < screen_rect.left:
    spaceship_X = screen_rect.left
if spaceship_X > screen_rect.right - spaceship_width:
    spaceship_X = screen_rect.right - spaceship_width
```

Make sure to use the single equals operator **`=`** (for assignment), not the double equals operator **`==`** (check for equality). And you will need to add a `spaceship_width` variable or constant, representing the width of the spaceship in pixels.

---

An alternative solution would be to switch to using a `rect` for the spaceship's dimensions, and then do:

```py
spaceship.rect = spaceship.rect.clamp(screen.get_rect())
```